# Creating a function that adds to two separate arrays depending on the input

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to combine two separate functions into a single function that can push a new item into one of two available arrays, depending on what the input is (in my situation, addToProsList or addToConsList).

Here is my current code. Having issues turning it into a single function (addToList()), because I'm not sure how I would be able to indicate which array it would enter with just the 'detail' parameter. I'm assuming I would need an if/else statement. I know this is simple, I am very stuck on how to approach this.

```js
var housePros = ['3 bed', '2 bath'];
var houseCons = ['over budget'];


function addToProsList(detail) {
  housePros.push(detail);
  console.log('Updated List: ', housePros);
}

function addToConsList(detail) {
  houseCons.push(detail);
  console.log('Updated List: ', houseCons);
}

addToProsList('big yard');
addToConsList('no garage');


function addToList(detail) {}
```

Comment: Can you change the input arrays to be arrays of objects? as in var houseAttr = [{attr: '3beds', pro: true}, {attr: 'over budget', pro: false}]

Comment: Yeah I can. I am going to mess around with that, ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will help you:

```
var housePros = ['3 bed', '2 bath'];
var houseCons = ['over budget'];

function addToList(detail, arr) {
    arr.push(detail);
    console.log('Updated List: ', arr);
}

addToList('big yard', housePros);
addToList('no garage', houseCons);
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be what you are looking for:

```js
var housePros = ['3 bed', '2 bath'];
var houseCons = ['over budget'];


function addToList(detail,cons) {
  // "first shot":
  // const list=window["house"+(cons?"Cons":"Pros")];
  // alternative (better) solution:
  const list=cons?houseCons:housePros;
  list.push(detail);
  console.log('Updated List: ', list);
}

addToList('big yard');
addToList('no garage',1);
```

The second argument of `addToList()` determines whether the item is to be pushed onto `housePros` (default) or `houseCons` (whenever the value `cons` is "truthy").

Comment: using `window` to access the vars is not that great solution

Comment: Very true - that is why I supplied the "alternative" too ... `window` always refers to the global object. In some situations the target arrays `housePros` and `houseCons` might not be defined there. However, my "alternative" solution *will* find them, as long as the function is defined in the same scope as the targeted arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second argument that indicates whether it's a pro or con:

```js
function addToList (detail, isPro) {
  (isPro ? housePros : houseCons).push(detail)
}

addToList('big yard', true)
addToList('no garage', false)
```

...or you could use an object with multiple lists:

```js
const houseAttribs = { pro: [], con: [] }

function addToList (attrib, detail) {
  houseAttrib[attrib].push(detail)
}

addToList('pro', 'big yard')
addToList('con', 'no garage')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let housePros = ['3 bed', '2 bath'];
let houseCons = ['over budget'];

// changing the addToList variable as you can pass the array
// in which you are adding the new elementelement
function addToList(detail, addList){
  addList.push(detail);
  addList.forEach(elem => console.log(elem));
  console.log("\n");
}

addToList('big yard', housePros);
addToList('no garage', houseCons);
```